# Anime about a powerful blue flower or gem

Tags: story-identification, anime

I watched this anime a long time ago.

The few scenes I barely remember are:

At one point there is a mother and a daughter (or son) in a house/greenhouse type area. The place starts shaking and the daughter (or son) gets trapped underneath and the mother takes the (flower or gem? it's blue) and runs away.

Another scene I remember is having to get to the top of the hotel and her sitting in the stall waiting for other people so she can go to the top floor with the crystal thing? Also when these people in like the military or army have to go outside with tablets and red dots would show up.

One of the main things was this blue crystal or flower thing (honestly it could be another color) was supposed to be really powerful.

Comment: You have some good info here but could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, do you know how long "a long time ago" is?

Comment: Made me think of Castle in the Sky but I doubt it's that.